# How to asses the total number of items?

Tags: algorithm, caching, statistics, computer-science

I have a stream processing system which has a cache.
cache size is 100K and the TTL for entries is 30 minutes. I want to come up with a metric that will help me *assessing* the total number of items that were pushed to the system.
Note: I want to do it without having a set that simply holds all the unique keys.

Here's what I thought:
I can listen to the event of entry eviction and have two counters:

1. eviction_full_capacity - it means that the entry was removed because another item needed to be added and the cache was full
2. eviction_ttl - the entry has expired and had to be removed

I can also count or check the rate of the input to the system.

Given the above, how can I assess the total number of unique items that were processed by the system?

Comment: In your system, every item is eventually evicted, and always within 30 minutes of its creation.  If you count the number of evictions, then you also have the number of creations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [HyperLogLog algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog) will estimate, fairly closely, the number of distinct items seen using only a small amount of memory.

If you're using Redis, this is [already implemented](https://redis.io/docs/data-types/hyperloglogs/).